# How can I access my old Yahoo! account?

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I want to access my old Yahoo! account but unfortunately the number associated with it no longer in service and there's no way of getting it back. Also I don't have any other email accounts associated with that account. What can I do to gain access to my account.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have active phone number or accessible email address associated with your Yahoo! account then visit [Yahoo! Help site](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?page=contact&y=PROD_ACCT&locale=en_IN&crumb=OtYzdtyHrUS), and fill this [form](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?page=contactform&locale=en_IN&token=Zh%2FBBVqXzLHlIbokbUqVWTUbuuQeXGkGKNe%2BTjm%2ByAN0IbtY2%2Fhf5YqttLssdbMaKoNbMkrurUznGzU4x84JfXHOTvRBWCrBehokLKqDJuYuZsykBOzrFBc5T%2F7kkXr3Hx%2BPsMDmo%2Bp2KigmnzFNJ2aKlAg%2FxvE4&selectedChannel=email-icon&yid=) to create a request. Later wait for them to come back and follow the instructions.